# Customize amp-list. How make autoloading and customize set of data

Tags: json, api, amp-html

Hy everyone! I have a two json-api (for example `/api/news.json` `/api/articles.json`) and I want to make a list with data from it with follow structure:

```
-- news-1
-- news-2
-- news-3
article-1
-- news-4
-- news-5
-- news-6
article-2
-- news-7
-- news-8
```

I'm load it by follow schema:

`result_list = []`

1. load news from `/api/news.json`
2. put all `news-data` to `news-queue`
3. while `news-queue` is not empty I'm do next:

   3.1. if `len(result_list) % 4 != 3` I'm trying to pull data to `result_list` from `news-queue`

   3.2. if `len(result_list) % 4 == 3` I'm trying to pull data to `result_list` from `articles-queue`

   - if `articles-queue` is empty I load articles from `/api/articles.json` and put all result-data to `articles-queue` and pull only one from `articles-queue` to `result_list`
   - If not empty I'm just pull article from `articles-queue` to `result_list` load articles from `/api/articles.json`

   3.3. if remainder of the division length of result-list on 4 is equal 3 I try to pull article from articles-queue.

I want to do this on client-side for cache only only simple api-requests (`/api/news.json` and `/api/articles.json`) and do not cache result list

I can do this on angular but how implement this logic using google-amp.

It's possible? I can't find any info about limits and callbacks in amp-list. How organize queue on client-side?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do this on your server side instead?

Comment: @fstanis Because it's design-level and I want to control design inside template. And I want to use existing API